# Don't get the simplest FireStore security rule to work as if it would not find my file - though looks like examples

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I don't get this running, no matter what I do. I have already removed all rules, nevertheless I get `simulated read denied`. I habe tried `companies/4U4kZKXkr3rHA6B04S5K` and `/companies/4U4kZKXkr3rHA6B04S5K` as location, copy pasted the document id and the collection multiple times, nothing... To me, it looks just like all the running examples, I found

What am I doing wrong?!

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: I used these rules before, which did not work:

```dart
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // the request object contains info about the authentication status of the requesting user
    // if the .auth property is not set, the user is not signed in
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }
    // return the current users entry in the employees collection
    function getEmployeeData() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/employees/$(request.auth.uid)).data
    }
    // check if the current user has access to specific company
    function accessCompany(companyId) {
      return isSignedIn() && getEmployeeData()['companyId'] == companyId;
    }
    
    // check if the current user has a specific role
    function hasRole(role) {
      return isSignedIn() && getEmployeeData()[role] == true;
    }
    // check if the user has any of the given roles (list)
    //function hasAnyRole(roles) {
    //  return isSignedIn() && getRoles().keys().hasAny(roles);
    //}
  }

  match /users/{user} {
    // anyone can see a specific users profile data (name, email etc), in a real scenario you might want to make this more granular
    allow get: if true;
    // noone can query for users
    allow list, create: if false;
    // users can modify their own data
    allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == user;
  }

  match /employees/{user} {
    // only allow admins to set roles. Of course a user should be able to retrieve its own designated roles
    allow get: if request.auth.uid == user || hasRole('admin');
    allow list: if hasRole('admin');
    allow update: if hasRole('admin');
    allow create, delete: if false;
  }

  match /companies/{document=**} {
    allow get, list, create, update, delete: if true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no read and write access is allowed to any document.  If you want to allow access to a document, you must have at least one rule that matches the query that would allow that access.  If you have commented out all your rules, then I would expect no reads or writes to be allowed.

Minimally, adding a rule like this will allow read access to all documents in the companies collection:

```
match /companies/{id} {
  allow read: if true;
}
```

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) on security rules to better learn how they work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had something similar before, which didn't work. Also your snippet doesn't (for me).  `rules_version = '2';service cloud.firestore { match /companies/{id} {allow read: if true; }
}` And believe me, I read the documentation and articles up and down

Comment: appologies, I guess I have looked to much on those few lines during the day, so I didn't notice that I removed 1 line too much. Now it works and I will try to get my other rules working one by one